# Solve system of equations $ \sqrt{2}x+3y= a $ and $x-\sqrt{3}y=4$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$ \sqrt{2}x+3y= a $$
$$x-\sqrt{3}y=4$$
What is the easiest way to solve this system? I always seem to get square roots of 2 and 3s and don't know what to do.

Comment: Multiply the second line by $-\sqrt{2}$, and add.

Comment: @RiktasMath Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

By elimination we have

- $ \sqrt{2}x+3y= a$
- $x-\sqrt{3}y=4\implies \sqrt 2x-\sqrt{6}y=4\sqrt 2$

and subtracting

- $3y+\sqrt 6 y=a-4\sqrt 2 \implies y=\frac{a-4\sqrt 2}{3+\sqrt 6 }$

and then we can find $x$ from

- $x-\sqrt{3}y=4\implies x=4+\sqrt{3}y=4+\sqrt{3}\frac{a-4\sqrt 2}{3+\sqrt 6 }$

Answer (score 2):

While it may not be the *easiest* way, here is a very systematic way:

It's a linear system that can be written as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{2} & 3\\
1 & -\sqrt{3}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a\\4
\end{pmatrix},
$$
so, due to
$$
\det{
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{2} & 3\\
1 & -\sqrt{3}
\end{pmatrix}
}
= -\sqrt{6}-3\neq 0
$$
there exists a unique solution. We can compute this solution by left multiplying the above equation with the inverse of the matrix which yields
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{2} & 3\\
1 & -\sqrt{3}
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
a\\4
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I guess you know how to compute this inverse.